# &amp;reg converted to ®

Tags: html

My original URL:

```
nourl=register-confirm&amp;reg_conf=yes&amp;title=&amp;firstname=prad&amp;lastname=prad&amp;email=ptarekj%40gmail.com&amp;custref=321043&amp;mobile=
```

My output URL is like below:

```
nourl=registerconfirm®_conf=yes&title=&firstname=prad&lastname=prad&email=ptarekj%40gmail.com&custref=321043&mobile=
```

After loading the customer registration page `&amp;reg` is getting converted to  `®` trademark symbol which I don't want. Can any one guide me how I do this?

Comment: You will need to be HTML-decoding that string at least once and then interpret it as HTML for that to happen. The solution is to properly handle HTML encoding/decoding in the right order at the right points. We can't really say much more about it than that without seeing what exactly you're doing with that string.

Comment: Some minor spelling errors corrected... Please don't use phrases like *thanks* in the question, you can thank an answerer by accepting and/or up-voting their answer.

Comment: You're decoding HTML entities one time too many. If you're decoding HTML entities before display in HTML, then of course the HTML engine will show &reg as ®.